# Jquery for auto fill textboxes in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am developing web application in asp.net 4.0
I have First name ,middle name and last name text boxes
and display name text box.while entering first along with middle and last name whole name will be display in Display Name text box using jquery

I am using

```
$(function () {
    $('input[id$=txtFName]').keyup(function () {
        var txtClone = $(this).val();
        $('input[id$=txtDisplayName]').val(txtClone);
    });
});
```

how can i concatenate first,middle and last name into Display Name text box.

Comment: instead of `input[id$=txtFName]` you can use this syntax: `#<%= txtFName.ClientID %>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:
    $(function () { 
        $('input[id$=txtFName], input[id$=txtMName], input[id$=txtLName]').keyup(function () {
             $('input[id$=txtDisplayName]').val(
    $('input[id$=txtFName]').val()+' '+$('input[id$=txtMName]').val()+ ' '+$('input[id$=txtLName]').val()); 
    }); });

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function () {
    var concatNames = function(first, middle, last) {
        //this is locale specific 
        return first + ' ' + middle + ' ' + last;
    };
    $('input[id$=txtFName], input[id$=txtMName], input[id$=txtLName]').keyup(function () {
        var fullName = concatNames($('input[id$=txtFName]').val(), $('input[id$=txtMName]').val(), $('input[id$=txtLName]').val());
        $('input[id$=txtDisplayName]').val(fullName);
    });
});
```

or you can mark all inputs with the same class and use class selector.

Answer (score 0):

You could just repeat your code 3 times for the 3 name boxes, concatenating the names correctly

```
$(function () {
    var $fname = $('input[id$=txtFNamee]');
    var $mname = $('input[id$=txtMName]');
    var $Sname = $('input[id$=txtSName]');
    $fName.keyup(function () {
        writeName($fname,$mname,$sname);
    });
    $mName.keyup(function () {
        writeName($fname,$mname,$sname);
    });
    $sName.keyup(function () {
        writeName($fname,$mname,$sname);
    });

    function writeName($f,$m,$s){
       $('input[id$=txtDisplayName]').val($f.val() + ' ' + $m.val() + ' ' + $s.val());
    }
});
```